# Alamofire upload videos from iPhone's library

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2, alamofire

I am developing an app that record movies and save them to the iPhone's library, now I need also to give the options to upload them to a private server. I am using Alamofire library but my server uses SCP as upload protocol, but I can just find http examples for the Alamofire library.

Does anyone has an example or can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are kinda aware of `UIImagePicker`.

this delegate method of `UIImagePicker`will give the video path and use this path for video uploading in `alamofire` request.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
{
    let video_file = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL
    if let selectedVideo : URL = (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL) {
        let selectorToCall = #selector(videoSaved(_:didFinishSavingWithError:context:))
        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(selectedVideo.relativePath, self, selectorToCall, nil)
        let videoData = try? Data(contentsOf: selectedVideo)
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        let video_url = documentsDirectory.appendingFormat("/video.mp4") // use this variable in alamofire
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: video_url ?? "")
        try! videoData?.write(to: url, options: [])
    }
}

// this method will save your video in photo library
@objc func videoSaved(_ video: String, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError!, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer)
{
    if let theError = error {
        print("error saving the video = \(theError)")
    }
    else {
       DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
       })
    }
}
```

video uploading with alamofire

```
func uploadImageVideoWithData(apiurl:String , param : [String : Any], videoUrl : URL )
{

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-type": "multipart/form-data","Accept": "application/json"]
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(videoUrl, withName: "key_name", fileName: "video_name.mp4", mimeType: "mp4")
        for (key, value) in param {
            multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }
    }, usingThreshold: 10 * 1024 * 1024,to: apiurl, method: .post, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response.result)
                    if let json = response.result.value {
                        print("JSON: \(json)")
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
        }
    })
}
```